# Questions about unofficial Xposed

Tags: discussion, questions

As everyone knows, back in the CyanogenMod days, we flagged questions about nightly releases, as they used to become obsolete fairly quickly and were too unstable to discuss.

Now, a similar situation presents itself to us: unofficial Xposed releases. As can be read in [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/flashable-xposed-framework-android-nougat/) XDA post, unofficial Xposed flashable `.zip` files are now a reality  for those who wish an early taste of Xposed on Nougat. While this may seem fantastic for the most adventurous of us, it also brings up a whole new array of issues which cannot be thoroughly classified. As rovo89, developer of Xposed, puts it,

> The worst thing about this is that the exact behavior would depend on
>   the ROM, or even how the user uses the device (now that apps are
>   compiled based on profiles). Modules would fail randomly and the
>   module developers would be wondering what they did wrong (answer:
>   nothing). If not all of the prerequisites are fulfilled, it’s a pretty
>   unreliable API.

It's evident that we, as well as module devs, would not be able to address questions about devices with said Xposed flavor. Most importantly, even if we did, such questions wouldn't even be consistent among users with the same device.

**Given the above, what stance should we take about questions featuring unofficial Xposed variants?** Note that this won't just apply to Xposed for Nougat, but for *any* unofficial Xposed in the future.

Comment: Now we have official Xposed. What?

Comment: @iBug From the above, `Note that this won't just apply to Xposed for Nougat, but for *any* unofficial Xposed in the future`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with the CyanogenMod nightlies, or any "pre-beta" ROM, they should be closed. The problem, whatever it happens to be, is probably not widely applicable, and is likely to be fixed in the short term. That makes the question virtually useless for future readers.

Just close them.

Comment: I second your idea. The problem is, that we lack a default flag option for these cases.

Comment: The site can only define so many default off-topic options. A custom option is more than sufficient.

Comment: Excellent. I shall wait until more attention to the topic has been garnered, or until tomorrow, and then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Answer accepted, since the upvotes denote a pretty good consensus.